# Can I use a laminated silicon steel transformer core as a low frequency boost converter core?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, inductance, saturation, buck-boost

Since laminated silicon steel is used in low frequency transformers, can't I also use it as an inductor in a low frequency boost converter, at maybe 100Hz, theoretically shouldn't this work as well as high frequency ferrite core boost converters?

Comment: You might be able to create a low frequency boost converter using a laminated steel core. Do you have any idea what the reluctance is of the core, or the maximum ampere-turns before saturation? I assume this is just for hobby purposes, because most efficient boost converters use much higher frequencies so that inductors and capacitors can be smaller.

Comment: I have a laminated silicon steel core used in old DVDs, to step down mains, I honestly don't know much about it's reluctance but I hope my description clues you in on the specs you need to give me your opinion on it, or maybe we can just speak in "ideal" terms so I can have a general perception of how and what happens if I were to use said laminated silicon steel core as a low frequency boost core

Comment: You can only store a certain amount of energy in an inductor before its core starts to saturate (and waste energy). Then switch off and the inductor transfers that energy to the output circuit (boosting the voltage). Yours will only do that 100x per second while the ferrite one operates 1000x faster. So, while it'll work, it won't work well. Wind a transformer on that core, it'll work better.

Comment: A conventional laminated steel core is designed for a transformer, not an inductor, which needs a much lower permeability to operate efficiently. If you don't understand the difference, you're not ready to roll your own boost converter.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the fact that your laminated steel core is designed to operate at mains frequencies?  It is pertinent to the answer.

Comment: Also, could you add the mains voltage it was used for. And, if you have taken the transformer apart, did you by any chance count the number of turns in the primary coil? (usually the coil with the thinner wire). All this information will be helpful if someone is willing to help you. Also, what voltages do you want to boost to? What is the voltage you will be supplying your converter? One more thing. If you disassembled the product the transformer came in, did you save the filter capacitors? You will need very _large_ filter capacitors for your boost converter, should you make one.

Comment: The caps in your circuit will be just silly big.  Designing a boost converter without the appropriate engineering courses is hard enough when you spend the money on the "right" components.  The higher the switching speed the less energy transferred per cycle and the easier it is to minimise ripple and overshoots, but also the harder layout becomes and the higher your core losses will be with a given core type.  I've been able to make a decent converter with as low as 10kHz, but with powdered iron cores, I can produce a much steadier output at 50kHz with the same drive circuit and smaller L.

Answer (score 1):

No, for at least two reasons.  The reasons that I know are:

**Eddy Current**

You mention that the core is designed to operate at mains frequencies.  Inductors that use laminations of steel are subject to a phenomenon called "eddy current"; basically, the thickness of the steel needs to be sized to the intended frequency of operation.  If you look at old audio transformers, you'll see that their laminations are thinner than those seen in power transformers.

**Core Saturation**

A boost converter works by storing energy in its inductor during part of the cycle, and then releasing it into the output during another part of the cycle.  A transformer can be designed so that the core doesn't need to store energy -- it just makes sure that energy going into the primary comes out the secondary.  Trying to use a transformer for your inductor core will saturate the core ("magnitize it too much").

Inductors for boost converters are either designed with outright air gaps (which, if you do the math, is where most of the energy is stored, not in the iron) that prevent this saturation, or they're designed with low-permeability materials that are much less prone to saturation.  Either way, they're lower inductance for their size than if they used all-steel cores, yet they can store more energy.

Comment: As a practical project, no, this isn't a good idea. The results will be unsatisfactory, except perhaps for a very low current. As a hobby experiment, it might be a useful learning tool.

Comment: But the iron saturates at 1.5 .. 2.2T while the ferrites saturate at 0.2 .. 0.5T; Actually the electrical silicone iron is excellent material for low frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no problem, given a couple considerations:

1. The laminations have to be taken apart and placed in individual stacks (all E, all I), so that an air gap between E and I can be added.  Inductors for mains frequency are constructed this way, but transformers are not (the laminations are alternated to keep gap to a minimum, which reduces operating current -- but for a boost converter, the operating (AC) current is exactly what you're looking for!).
2. The operating frequency is quite low, obviously, so the power density sucks in comparison to ferrite, quite large capacitors are needed, and loop response is very slow (much less than F<sub>SW</sub> of course).  Current-mode control alleviates this a bit, but it's still a lot of materials for not a lot of capacity.
3. Flux density is as usual; at 100Hz, running near saturation is acceptable.  But notice the flux can only be unipolar (i.e., it's biased with DC), so you lose some capacity with respect to a transformer at the same frequency.  But this also isn't a big deal, as the peak-to-peak flux density will be smaller anyway (you likely want to avoid DCM), which allows higher frequency too.  I would guess up to 500Hz wouldn't be terrible for standard mains frequency laminations, if ran at a low ripple fraction (say, under 10%).

Iron-core inductors are nothing unusual in [ancient] SMPS history; early regulators were made with SCRs (or even older, thyratrons), switching mains frequency (or a fraction of it: phase control) into an inductor ("choke-input filter").  Later, switching frequencies of some ~kHz were used, such as in various mini- and super-computers.  There have been examples even up to 20-30kHz; the inductance is simply made large enough that the eddy current losses aren't significant.  (I've seen some examples of these before, though I don't recall what, right now; maybe one was a PDP-11 something?)